# Query to Pandas dataframe

Tags: c#, python, pandas, python-3.5

I have the following data:

```
Id | PrimaryName | SecondaryName | Value
---+-------------+---------------+-------
 0 | PN0         | SN0           | 3
 1 | PN0         | SN1           | 5
 2 | PN0         | SN2           | 6
 3 | PN1         | SN3           | 5
 4 | PN1         | SN4           | 6
 5 | PN1         | SN5           | 7
 6 | PN2         | SN6           | 1
 7 | PN2         | SN7           | 2
 8 | PN2         | SN8           | 3
```

Actually, it is something like a key-value pair, with `SecondaryName` as key and `Value` as, hm, value, with additional column `PrimaryName`.
My task is, by looking at only the two entries with the biggest value for each `PrimaryName`, to determine the two biggest `PrimaryName`s.

For example, for `PN0` two biggest values are 5 and 6, for `PN1` are 6 and 7, for `PN2` are 2 and 3. That means that the biggest `PrimaryName`s are `PN0` with the score of 11, and `PN1` with the score of 13.
**The desirable result is just an ordered list of `PrimaryName`s => `['PN1', 'PN0']`**

As someone who's rather proficient with C#, that looked like a quite easy task, solvable with the following query:

```
var result = table.GroupBy(r => r.PrimaryName)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        PrimaryName = g.Key,
        Value =  g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value).Take(2).Sum(e => e.Value)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Value)
    .Take(2)
    .Select(e => e.PrimaryName)
    .ToList();
```

Yet now I have to repeat it in Python, specifically pandas.

So far I conjured only the following part of a query:

```
df.groupby('PrimaryName')[['PrimaryName', 'Value']]
```

I suspect that to perform calculations like I did in this C# line `g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value).Take(2).Sum(e => e.Value)` I will have to define a new dataframe with a temporary column, but I am not sure how exactly.

Can anybody please help me with that?

---

There is actually a bit more to the question. This task is the part of a course on pandas, and, judging by the fact that `groupby` is the next weeks topic, I might be on the wrong path, or at least I might be missing out something easy and obvious.

Comment: @Zero I did, actually: `['PN1', 'PN0']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  double [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) - first  for get `2` top values and then `sum` them first and then for another top 2 index values:

```
L = df.groupby('PrimaryName')['Value']
      .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).sum())
      .nlargest(2)
      .index
      .tolist()
print (L)
['PN1', 'PN0']
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('PrimaryName')['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).sum()))
PrimaryName
PN0    11
PN1    13
PN2     5
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
L = df.sort_values('Value', ascending=False)
      .groupby('PrimaryName')['Value']
      .apply(lambda x: x.head(2).sum())
      .nlargest(2)
      .index
      .tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
In [5181]: (df.groupby(['PrimaryName'])['Value']
              .nlargest(2)
              .sum(level=0)
              .nlargest(2)
              .index.tolist())
Out[5181]: ['PN1', 'PN0']
```

---

Details

```
In [5185]: df.groupby(['PrimaryName'])['Value'].nlargest(2)
Out[5185]:
PrimaryName
PN0          2    6
             1    5
PN1          5    7
             4    6
PN2          8    3
             7    2
Name: Value, dtype: int64

In [5186]: df.groupby(['PrimaryName'])['Value'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0)
Out[5186]:
PrimaryName
PN0    11
PN1    13
PN2     5
Name: Value, dtype: int64

In [5187]: df.groupby(['PrimaryName'])['Value'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0).nlargest(2)
Out[5187]:
PrimaryName
PN1    13
PN0    11
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Well, thank you, Zero, for your thorough explanation! Now, thanks to you, I am better at understanding these pandas functions! Cheers!